# Trouble importing Fiona in Python

Tags: python, conda

I am trying to use the Fiona module in Python, but am having trouble getting it to work. After issuing `conda install fiona`, the installation using conda seems fine, but when I issue `import fiona`, I get the following error message: `module 'fiona' has no attribute '_loading'`

Has anyone else encountered this problem? The version of Fiona that I have tried to install is 1.18.18.

It seems related to the issue identified [here](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/806), but I am not exactly sure what this means. I am running conda in an ArcGIS Pro environment, and so don't want to create any problems.

Comment: Could you please edit your post to include how you installed the libraries?

Answer (score 3):

I used pip instead, and it worked. `pip install geopandas`. I did this because `geopandas` installs fiona. I should have tried this before posting.

Comment: I tried this and just got about 6 screens of red text as pip continually tried older and older versions of fiona, finally picked 1.7.13 downloaded some stuff, gave another two screens of red error text and died. That was with a new clean environment.

Comment: @kpierce8 did you figure out how to install geopandas?

Comment: the installation I finally got working involved going to python 3.9 where fiona seems to be playing nicely with others. This doesn't solve the running in an environment with arcpy. I'm using it for a reporting module and I pretty much just use that environment to generate reports.

Answer (score 0):

create new environment as "geo_env" as explained for installing geopandas.
Now:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:/Users/UserName/anaconda3/envs/geo_env/Lib/site-packages")
# print(sys.path)
import geopandas as gpd
```

Your problem should be solved